# Receiving status 400 when fetching with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

My Google Books clone application has a user submit their inputted query, then the response data is displayed.

Following the [schema validation example](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Quickstart) provided by React Hook Form docs, I receive `Error: Request failed with status code 400`. What am I doing wrong?

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
const [books, setBooks] = useState({ items: [] });

const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  formState: { errors }
} = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(schema)
});

const handleBookFetch = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}?q=${query}`);
    setBooks(result.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleBookFetch)}>
  <label name="book">
    Search the world's most comprehensive index of full-text books.
  </label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="book" {...register("book")} onChange={(event) => setQuery(event.target.value)} />
    <p>{errors.book?.message}</p>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `query` state is never updated, you're not even assigning a name to the `setQuery` function that useState returns. So, `query` will *always* have its default value of "". Your server is likely returning 400 Bad Request because you're sending it an empty query string.

I think React Hook Form passes your data as an object to your handleSubmit function, so you can get the query's current value from that:

```
const handleBookFetch = async (data) => {
  // ...
  // "book" is the name of the input element
  const result = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL}?q=${data.book}`);
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm now able to search, but I'm receiving the wrong responses. When I fetch `${data.query}`, I receive a list of books with `undefined` in their title. When I fetch `${query}`, I receive a list of books with `object` in their title.

Comment: I recommend using `console.log()` on the response data to verify it matches the shape you're expecting. If the shape matches and the data is just wrong, then the problem might be on the server, and you'll need to troubleshoot that.

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you for your guidance! `const result = await axios.get(${API_BASE_URL}?q=${data.book});`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I didn't notice that the query input's `name` is "book".